# Better understanding PG logs and replication flow

Tags: postgresql

I've working with PG and replication, but the exact sequence of the process is not quite clear to me.

Please correct my understanding:

- I execute an update SQL statement against a database.
- The change is written as a transaction, and that transaction is placed in the log buffer.
- The log buffer flushes to the WAL log upon commit, then streams to the standby in the case of streaming replication.
- The transaction is then written to the cache, then the disk.

Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: Might I ask why this was downvoted? I wanted to validate my understanding based on the doco I read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct flow is:

- before the data are modified in shared buffers, transaction redo information is written to WAL buffers
- the primary's WAL sender reads this information and sends it to the standby's WAL receiver, without waiting for `COMMIT` or anything else on the primary
- the redo information is written to WAL on the standby and flushed to disk
- then, the redo information is applied at the standby, so that the data in shared buffers are modified

Comment: When will the actual change be made? And what if the standby cannot reach the primary?

Comment: If the standby cannot reach the primary, there is no replication, because the connection between the servers is started by the standby. Which actual change do you mean? The data on the standby are modifies in the last step.

Comment: Apologies, that was not worded well, when is the change on the primary written to disk? Presumably before or after step 3?

Comment: It is independent. Usually before that, but it could be afterwards too. That's what "asynchronous" replication is about.